# Magento 2 Error - Custom created product attribute value not save in magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.2

I created a custom product attribute using installer script.
Attribute was created successfully and I can view it in product adding page in admin.

If I save the product the attribute value is not saving.

My Steps are..

```
<?php
namespace Emedia\ProductAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{ 
private $eavSetupFactory;


public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0') < 0){

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'location_id',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'group' => 'General',/* Group name in which you want 
                                          to display your custom attribute */
            'type' => 'int',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Location', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'FME\GoogleMapsStoreLocator\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                            /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                                /*Scope of your attribute */
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false
        ]
    );
    }
}
}
```

My resource file Options.php

```
<?php
namespace FME\GoogleMapsStoreLocator\Model\Config\Source;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

protected $optionFactory;
protected $collectionFactory;


public function __construct(OptionFactory $optionFactory,        
    \FME\GoogleMapsStoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Storelocator\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
{
    $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;  
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    //you can use this if you want to prepare options dynamically  
}

/**
 * Get all options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllOptions()
{
     $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->setOrder('creation_time', 'DESC');
    $this->_options = [['label'=>'Please select', 'value'=>'']];
    foreach($collection as $custom)
    {
        $this->_options[] = ['label'=> $custom->getStoreName(), 'value' => $custom->getGmapsId()];
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

public function getOptionText($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function getFlatColumns()
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    return [
        $attributeCode => [
            'unsigned' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'extra' => null,
            'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Custom Attribute Options  ' . $attributeCode . ' column',
        ],
    ];
}
}
```

After upgrade command I can see the attributes in magento 2 admin back end product adding form too like this

[image]

If I save the product the location is not save in back end and not view in edit form.

What steps I skip, can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here i have missed the **backend** model. this answer may help some one in future.

I change my install script like below

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'location_id',/* Custom Attribute Code */
    [
        'group' => 'General',/* Group name in which you want 
                                      to display your custom attribute */
        'type' => 'int',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Location', /* lablel of your attribute*/
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => 'FME\GoogleMapsStoreLocator\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                        /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                            /*Scope of your attribute */
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => '',
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false
    ]
);
```

only changed this line

```
'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run this below command:

```
update eav_attribute set backend_model = "Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend" where attribute_code = "location_id"
```

Please let me know if it works.